# TreeView multiple selection does not work correctly after changing selection without UI

Tags: gtk3, pygobject

This is potentially a bug, though perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

**Brief description**

Basically, I have found that using "Shift+Arrows" to do multiple selection in a `Gtk.TreeView` does not work correctly after changing the selection using `Gtk.TreeSelection.select_iter`. On the other hand, if you change the selection by clicking on a row and then pressing "Shift+Arrows", the selection behaves as one would expect.

I should note that if you change the selected row by calling `Gtk.TreeSelection.select_iter`, the UI updates as you would expect and calling `Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected_rows()` returns the rows it should. It's only when you then try to select multiple rows using the arrow keys that you get strange behavior.

This is perhaps best illustrated in this self contained example, which I've tried to make as simple as possible:

**Code**

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TreeViewBug(Gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

    # Create model consisting of row path and a name
    self.treeModel = Gtk.ListStore(int, str)
    self.treeModel.append([0, 'alice'])
    self.treeModel.append([1, 'bob'])
    self.treeModel.append([2, 'chad'])
    self.treeModel.append([3, 'dan'])
    self.treeModel.append([4, 'emma'])

    self.treeView = Gtk.TreeView()
    self.treeView.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn('path', Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
    self.treeView.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn('name', Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=1))
    self.treeView.set_model(self.treeModel)

    # Allow for multiple selection
    self.treeView.get_selection().set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)

    self.add(self.treeView)

  def run(self):
    self.show_all()

    # Focus the TreeView so we can test multiple select via keyboard without clicking on a row
    self.treeView.grab_focus()

    # Manually change the selected row to the row with "chad"
    chadIter = self.treeModel[2].iter
    self.treeView.get_selection().select_iter(chadIter)

    print('Press "Shift+Down" and see what happens')
    print('  it should select "chad, dan", but instead it selects "bob, chad"')
    print('Afterwards, try clicking on "chad" and then pressing Shift+Down. It should behave normally')

    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tv = TreeViewBug()
  tv.run()
```

**Things I've tried**

I initially encountered the bug when my code changed the selected row via `Gtk.TreeSelection.select_iter` in response to a button click.

I've also tried:

- adding a custom select function (`Gtk.TreeSelection.set_select_function`)
- clearing the selection before changing it (`Gtk.TreeSelection.unselect_all`)
- changing the selection asynchronously (`GLib.idle_add`).
- redrawing `TreeView` after changing selection

**Speculations**

I'm guessing that `TreeView`/`TreeViewSelection` has some internal state variable tracking selection and row that, for some reason, isn't getting properly updated when `TreeSelection.select_iter` is called. These variables are probably related to UI features, because `TreeSelection.get_selected_rows` still works properly. Also it makes sense the UI would need additional state information since the UI logic of multiple selection depends on previous UI interaction (Shift+Down behaves differently when extending a selection depending on whether you initially selected upwards or downwards)

Comment: To clarify, I'm running pygobject version 3.34 on python 3.7.4 on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a Gtk.TreeView uses MVC, you actually need to set the cursor of the treeview. This may affect the rest of the program, depending on what you are doing. Example:

```
#chadIter = self.treeModel[2].iter
#self.treeView.get_selection().select_iter(chadIter)
path = 2
column = self.treeView.get_column(0)
edit = False
self.treeView.set_cursor(path, column, edit)
```

Comment: Interesting, so there is a cursor and a selection which are stored separately. I had no idea. Didn't see that anywhere in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: There is no one place in the docs that clarifies all this behaviour. You learn a bit here and a bit there, and a bit on StackOverflow...